# Passing the re-authenticating page with Cheerio and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am working on a task that uses cheerio to grab some page content and show on another app.

The site I am grabbing is authenticated(actually a console), and I have the username and password, for this, I use request-promise npm package to help me for this logic. It works well for most of the cases, but it fails because some of the routes would not return the page content via HTTP Get method but redirect/return to the page that required me to input the username and password again, and then it will redirect to the page I want. **So I am wondering how I can pass the reauthentication page directly and grab the content I want.**

Here are my code samples:

```
    function req(url) {
        return rp({ // request-promise
            uri: `${url}`,
            auth: {
                username,
                password,
                sendImmediately: true
            },
            method: "GET"
        });
    }

     const [pageA, pageB] = await Promise.all([
            req('pageAUrl').then(JSON.parse).then(...),
            req('pageBUrl').then(JSON.parse).then(...)
        ]);

        let $ = cheerio.load(pageA); // when I load Page A, I find the http returns the reauthentication Page require input password and username again!

        $ = cheerio.load(pageB);  // page B works correctly!
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unless you can find a better way to ask this question, your best bet will probably be switching to puppeteer /. nightmarejs for whatever you're trying to do here.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, I will take a look at that.